# CSS Bug in Careers on IE7

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, design

In IE7 the post a Job page looks odd as text is misaligned and buttons are cut off.

I can understand no IE6 support but IE7 is still commonly used.

[image]

Comment: Sorry same browser but all normal on my box.

Comment: I can confirm - we'll look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hi John, this should now be fixed.

Comment: I can confirm it looks ok now.